# Clone Entire OS over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, centos-6

I have a CENTOS server that was recently compromised.  However, I used to be friendly with a professor who taught computer security, and I would like to give this person a chance to go over the old files to see what happened.  I have the storage space, is there a way for a CENTOS server to Clone itself entirely before I ghost it?

Answer (score 1):

You may be misleading some readers with the "clone" word.  Generally you clone a system to produce a running system that is identical.  If you have identical hardware this can be done quite successfully as I managed 40 remote servers with cloning long ago.  If you do not have exact hardware, then you may face some challenges getting the clone to run, although it is far easier than doing this with a MS OS.

If the hardware is similar (ie x86 cpu or 64 bit and sata drives in the same order) then you may be able to cpio your files from one box to the freshly formatted filesystem on the other.

You will need to run the destination on a Live CD or some such and run a command like:

On the source machine:

```
cd /rootoforig
find . -depth | cpio -o | nc -w 3 1234
```

On the destination machine:

```
nc -l -p 1234 | cpio -imduv
```

If bandwidth is a concern, you can insert a compress in the middle of the pipe.
nc is NetCat

This will replicate your filesystem verbatum, with duplicate ownership/permissions/times, which can be of critical importance in diagnosing an exploit.

This data transfer is NOT encrypted, and will run much faster because of that.

You should now have a replicate of the filesystem (better vernacular than "clone")

If all goes well, you should be able to run a grub command to configure the boot.  I have used this quite a lot, although I mount the second disk locally and use a slightly different command:

```
cd /rootoforig
find . -depth | cpio -pmduv /mnt/destinationfs
```

The -depth tells find to send the files in a folder before the folder, this allows the access times/ownership on the folders to be set correctly.

Similar results may be obtained with rsync.  For me, rsync did not exist when I first started doing this.

Finally, as an alternative, if you truly want to **clone** the system, then you can run something similar to:

```
# on the server w/ ip 12.3.4:
nc -l 12345 | gzip -d | dd bs=16M of=computer-dd-image.img

# on the source/client:
dd bs=16M if=/dev/sda | gzip -c | nc 1.2.3.4 12345
```

Netcat is unencrypted of course, and changing the blocksize and adding gzip compression should increase the transfer speed some over the network. You could also do it this way over ssh, at the cost of speed:

```
dd if=/dev/sda | ssh username@servername.net dd of=computer-dd-image.img
```

This enables more through forensics analysis with software like [Autopsy and Scapel](http://www.sleuthkit.org/) or [EnCase](https://www.guidancesoftware.com/products/Pages/encase-forensic/overview.aspx).

Comment: Good answer, and addressing of the use of 'clone' terminology. Many forensics packages such as scalpel, formost or Encase will want to see a cloned image. This can be done as Timbo described, except using `dd` or `dcfldd` rather than `cpio`, over `nc`  to work with raw blocks. See the Forensics Wiki for more details: http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Category:Disk_Imaging

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
 scp -prv  root@compromised:/ /mount/point
```

/mount/point is the mount point of your image. The options are: *-r* recursively copy everything inside the specified directory, descending down all branches of the tree; *-p* preserve modification times, access times, and modes, and *-v* verbose mode, which may be useful given the size of the task.

You could have done the same with *rync*, of course.

Comment: To keep ownership & permissions, the destination needs to be `root@` as well. And better run the client on the target machine, specifying `root@compromised:/` as source... you don't want to type any passwords into it, really.

Comment: @grawity You are entirely right, added this to solution above